Residential vacancy switch with "dry" (relay-isolated) contact switching
My Panasonic FV-0510VSC1 bathroom fan has a humidity sensor on it that automatically turns it on if someone's taking a shower.
The wiring diagram shows two switches: In addition to the normal LINE IN with hot/neutral/ground wire connections, it also has a pair of red leads that can be wired up to a "general manual wall switch":


These red leads are "dry" contacts that only facilitate control, and don't supply any power to the fan. In my case, the fan is always powered (i.e. no power switch), and my current (dumb) wall switch is connected to the red wires. When the switch is on, the control circuit closes and the fan turns on. When it's off, the humidity sensor determines whether the fan activates.
Sometimes the wall switch gets left on, so I want to upgrade it to an motion detector switch with a timer where it turns off after a certain period of inactivity.
I tried installing an Eaton VS306U with the hot leg disconnected but have been unsuccessful - it seems to need 120V to run the sensor electronics, which would also output 120V - something I need to avoid at all costs.

I'm also looking at the Panasonic FV-WCD-01 which mentions dry contact switching with 24VAC, but also says that 24VAC will be output. (I'm not worried about the output since I'd only be switching the red control signal, but it doesn't say whether the motion detecting aspect of the switch will actually function if the control line doesn't carry that much potential.)

Anyone have experience wiring up something like this?
Related: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/264995/105184

Is installing a relay an option?

Might be. Would want to encase it somehow though, not something floating around in the wall haha

No idea if it would work here, but what about a timer switch instead of an occupancy switch?  There are several options for timer switches, e.g. Leviton R02-DT160-0LW.

I don't think that Leviton will work, looks like there's line voltage on the output leg. This is the base problem I'm seeing with most options on the market. Need one that can act like a relay.

Hmm maybe Eaton OSP10M might work...

Though not advertised as such, I found the Eaton OSM10M works in this exact manner.
It has five lead wires:

HOT (black)
RELAY IN (orange)
RELAY OUT (red)
3-WAY (blue, not shown in this application)
GROUND (green)


When the switch is turned on, the internal relay engages, closing the RELAY side circuitry. The relay in/out lines are connected to the two red control wires from the fan (order not important - these wires, when connected, complete a circuit used as a data pathway for the fan to poll itself. If it receives the poll signal, it knows the switch is on, and will run the fan.)
It also has multiple operating modes. Besides the factory default setting of occupancy (AUTO on, AUTO off) mode, it can also be programmed for vacancy (MANUAL on, AUTO off), manual-only (MANUAL ON, MANUAL OFF), or even "disable manual" (same as occupancy mode, except the switch does not respond to button presses).
